# sp_Blitz error: "File '' either does not exist.."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-blitz

- SQL Server 2008 v10.0.5538.0
- sp_Blitz v5.5

I'm trying to run `sp_Blitz` for the first time and getting this error message:

```
sp_Blitz @CheckUserDatabaseObjects = 0
```

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>   Msg 567, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 3863 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   File '' either does not exist or is not a recognizable trace file. Or there was an error opening the file.

What may be causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a weird [bug](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/962) that only pops up on some instances of SQL Server when the Trace File path has problems. I can't diagnose those, but we took some steps to avoid that bug which are in the latest version of sp_Blitz.

Please head over to [firstresponderkit.org](http://firstresponderkit.org) to grab the newest version, and file an issue at the GitHub repo if you run into anything else.

Thanks!